# Is it possible to create a link to the cp that shows all pending entries of a section?

Tags: control-panel, url

As the question states, I want to create a link that sends a user to the entries page only showing the pending entries.

I tried using the cpUrl function but can't seem to get it directly to the pending entries status, just the entries page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

This is now possible in Craft 4. More specifically, it's now possible to ping a URL similar to this one...

```
/admin/entries/yourSection&status=pending
```

Depending on where you want the link, you may still need a tool to add a link in the Control Panel. As pointed out by @iamkeir in the comments, the CP Nav plugin is a good choice for adding a link to the main CP navigation.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

The short answer is "no, this isn't currently possible".

With any luck, it will be added to the upcoming Craft 4.

It seems like a simple enough feature request, I'd be surprised if it hasn't been asked before. If you don't see a ticket [on the Github repo](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues), feel free to open a new issue. [This discussion](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/discussions/8942) seems close, but is weirdly underrecognized.

Comment: ah too bad, would be nice if it does get added in Craft 4.
Will create a ticket for it if I don't find any similar one. 
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Anyone know if this _was_ added to Craft 4? Been looking at https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/cp-nav/ in meantime

Comment: @iamkeir I believe it is now possible in Craft 4, you should be able to ping a URL similar to this: `/admin/entries/yourSection&status=pending`. You may still need the CP Nav plugin to create an actual link for it.